# "I came" or "I went"

Tags: grammar

Which one is grammatically fine?
I was surprised but then
having no knowledge about this issue. I came/went
back to my city.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in your city right now, you will say,

> I came back to my city.

If you are some where else, you will say,

> I went back to my city.

But the two could be more or less interchangeable in some contexts.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as simple as this. In a personal narrative, you might say _I came back to my city_ even if you aren't there any more. It would have no difference in objective meaning from _I went back to my city_, but it would have an narrative force of pulling the discourse into that period when the city was my home.

Comment: @ColinFine Yeah. You are right. But in this case this short explanation might work. There are books out there that cover these topics in great detail. That's why I added that last sentence in there.

Answer (score -1):

This is not so much an English language question than a question for any language in the world. It's a logic question. A logic question that involves indirection.

For example,

- borrow vs lend
- take vs give
- come vs go

You should use whichever indirection or word that your logical mind tells you.

Comment: No, this is simply not true. Every language I know has words for _go_ and _come_, but the boundary they draw between them varies from language to language. _Come_ is typically associated with where the speaker is now, but in English we can say _Come to the restaurant_ even if I have not yet started my own journey to the restaurant; but other languages do not all allow that. Appeals to logic are rarely useful in discussing language.

Comment: So, Colin, you don't agree with Noah's answer?

Comment: I've just commented on that answer. But I'm actually addressing your answer at a different level: you can assume that Muhammad's own language has words meaning _come_ and _go_ with essentially the difference you are talking about. The fact that he has asked the question suggests that it is the differences between English and his own language in this respect which puzzle him.

Comment: I think the sentiment is the same in any language. "Come to the pub" in any language means "I have a sentimental attachment to the pub", regardless if I am presently at the pub. "Go to the pub" means, "I have yet to acquire a sense of belonging there", or to emphasize I am not presently there. It's the same in any of the languages I have familiarity with.

Comment: For example in Indonesian, "Mari ke rumah saya" = "Come to my house", even though I am speaking it in my office. If we say "Go to my house" = "Pergi ke rumah saya" it is meant to emphasize that the listener should imperatively go to my house, perhaps, due to an urgent situation. The same in Hebrew or Tamil. "Come" is welcoming. "Go" is imperative.

Comment: I wish to invite Muhammad to contaminate the English language and infect all of us with his logical understanding of come vs go, according to his culture. Use it to your personal preference. This is, after all, what the English language is about - assimilating various cultures and forming dialectical meanings that the whole world could enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

Went and came are not the same, because when so ever "went" come across in a sentence , it's describing somewhere else not your place,
But "came" can be use when you are in the place that the event happened